# How to change text color where background of section is white or black

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change color of menu if menu scrolling is over background:black then menu text should be white or if background is white then menu text should be black.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-side-navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#example-one"><span>Example One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-two"><span>Example Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-three"><span>Example Three</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-four"><span>Example Four</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-five"><span>Example Five</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-six"><span>Example Six</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="example-one"></div>
<div id="example-two"></div>
<div id="example-three"></div>
<div id="example-four"></div>
<div id="example-five"></div>
<div id="example-six"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.example-one {
  background: black;
}
.example-two { 
  background: black;
}
.example-three { background: white }
.example-four { background: black }
.example-five { background: white; }
.example-six { background: black; }
```

Comment: Are you already detecting when the background divs have been scrolled into view? You surely don't want us to write the whole thing.

Comment: You'll need some javascript for this most likely. If you are just using black and white, then it is simple, grab the background color, if black, change menu color to white, if white, change menu color to black (in JS). If using more colors, you will have to calculate the 'brightness' of the background and adjust accordingly. There are many examples of 'brightness' calculations from google searching.

Comment: Maybe make text white with a black text shadow then it will work everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demonstration using Jquery.

- Make use of *variables* to store the **scroll position**, and **position for the elements offset from top** at which you want the color to change i.e element1 and element2 in this example.
- Check the *offset from **top of the scroll** against the **offset of the elements top position*** when the document is scrolled using `$(document).scroll(function())` .
- Apply the appropriate CSS color or styles to the elements **according to the conditional statements**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scroll_pos = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    var element1 = $('#backgrund2').offset().top;
    var element2 = $('#backgrund3').offset().top;
    if (scroll_pos < element2 && scroll_pos > element1) {
      $(".fixed-side-navbar a").css('color', 'black');
    } else {
      $(".fixed-side-navbar a").css('color', 'white');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed-side-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fixed-side-navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#backgrund1,
#backgrund2,
#backgrund3 {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 700px;
}

#backgrund2 {
  background: white;
}

#backgrund3 {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed-side-navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#background1"><span>Intro</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#background2"><span>MSQ</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#background3"><span>ICM</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec2"><span>Section two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec3"><span>Section three</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec4"><span>Section four</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="backgrund1"></div>
<div id="backgrund2"></div>
<div id="backgrund3"></div>
```

**Updated:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scroll_pos = 0;
  var $window  = 7*$(window).height()/10; //Since, top=70%
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop()+$window;
    var element1 = $('#example-one').offset().top;
    var element2 = $('#example-two').offset().top;
    var element3 = $('#example-three').offset().top;
    var element4 = $('#example-four').offset().top;
    var element5 = $('#example-five').offset().top;
    var element6 = $('#example-six').offset().top;


    if ((scroll_pos >= element3 && scroll_pos < element4) || (scroll_pos >= element5 && scroll_pos < element6)) {
      $(".fixed-side-navbar a").css('color', 'black');
    } else {
      $(".fixed-side-navbar a").css('color', 'white');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fixed-side-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70%;
  left: 0;
}

.fixed-side-navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#example-one {
  background: black;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

#example-two {
  background: black;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

#example-three {
  background: white;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

#example-four {
  background: black;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

#example-five {
  background: white;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

#example-six {
  background: black;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed-side-navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#example-one"><span>Example One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-two"><span>Example Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-three"><span>Example Three</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-four"><span>Example Four</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-five"><span>Example Five</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-six"><span>Example Six</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="example-one"></div>
<div id="example-two"></div>
<div id="example-three"></div>
<div id="example-four"></div>
<div id="example-five"></div>
<div id="example-six"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Highdef, Thank you for your answer. I made a change in my request becuause your result that you have offer isn't giving me a result, or at least my request was different.
If you just give one a look, please check my request with changes.

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi Are you doing this in bootstrap?

Comment: So, what exactly are you looking for? I mean what changes from the current answer I gave, it is changing its text according to the background, when the background is black, the the text is white and vice versa.

Comment: I have different ID for example for one DIV with background:black, i have #example-one,#example-two, #example-four(just for example) or for DIV with backgroud: white, i have #example-three...

Comment: Okay, so they could be random.

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi I added an updated answer, you would need to use if/else conditions to check when the scroll position is between which elements and change the text color according to that. You cannot just automatically detect the background-color, you have to make use of this kind of method.

Comment: Highdef, Thank you :)

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi You got it?

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi No problem :)

Comment: Highdef, sorry for another thing, what if top of menu is .fixed-side-navbar{ top:50% } (or .fixed-side-navbar { bottom:0, left:0})?

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi You can subtract that much offset of top from the elements. Updated the fiddle. If it is 50%, then subtract $(window).height()/2 (which is 50%) , if it is fixed like 200px, subtract 200px. Basically if it is in percantage, convert % to fraction. if 50%, 1/2, 25%, 1/4, 75%, 3/5 and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161967/discussion-between-highdef-and-rexhep-rexhepi).

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi Updated again, just add the amount of offset calculate in $window variable to the scroll_pos instead of subtracting from every element. If you found the answer helpful, be sure to upvote it :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to the html:

```
.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.nav li {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.nav li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav li:hover > a {
  color: #000000;
}
```